# Barcode rendering in RMarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, barcode

While trying to render a barcode using shinyBarcode package in Rmarkdown, I have difficulty printing the barcode as an image. The function barcodeOutput works in a Shiny app. However in an Rmarkdown document, I cannot get the rendered barcode. Can you suggest a solution. Thanks

````
```{r br,  include=TRUE}   
    ProdID <- "123"
    renderBarcode(ProdID)
    barcodeOutput(ProdID)
```
````

Comment: Are you using `include = TRUE`?

Comment: Yes, I have used that. I have also presented the revised code now.